# How did they cremate Shaul at the end of Shmuel 2?

Tags: navi-prophets

It seems that once a group of brave warriors retrieved Shaul Hamelech's body parts they cremated him and then buried the remains. How does this match up with the general view in Judaism that prohibits creation?

Comment: The verse notes that the bones were buried (II Sh'mu'el 31:13). Rashi's interpretation (per Targum Yonasan) is that what was burned in the previous verse were Sha'ul's accoutrements (a practice for kings mentioned in tractate *'Avoda Zara*). Radak suggests a possible alternative that they burned the flesh away from the bones because it had decomposed so badly that it was disgraceful to leave the flesh in its current state (Malbim says chemicals were used to burn away the flesh, which is permissible according to Rashba 1:369).

Comment: @Fred that sounds like an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the commentary. Unfortunately I am dealing with someone who does not give much deference to the interpretation of rishonim and achronim. Is there any other way to prove that cremation was not done?